# Inner Join results in no records returned even when join criteria exist in both tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to perform an Inner Join on two tables and no records are being returned. Both tables are being joined on Postal Code, which is stored as a VARCHAR(50).

```
    SELECT 
        T1.Name
       ,T1.PostalCode
       ,T2.Address
    FROM FirstTable as T1
        INNER JOIN SecondTable as T2 ON T1.PostalCode = T2.PostalCode
```

The result is no records are returned. I tried trimming white space from the Postal Code field in both tables and still have no results.

I then tried to narrow down the issue by using a separate select statement. The select statement below returns the record with the Postal Code and Address:

```
    SELECT PostalCode, Address, FROM SecondTable WHERE PostalCode = 'A1A1A1'
```

When I try this query on the first table, no records are returned:

```
    SELECT Name, PostalCode FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode = 'A1A1A1'
```

This is very perplexing because manually viewing the table in Excel reveals a record exists for the postal code.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to execute the following query: `SELECT PostalCode FROM FirstTable INTERSECT SELECT PostalCode FROM SecondTable` ? If it returns no rows, then you don't have any rows in the two tables with the same PostalCode, and thus you will not get any rows when you join them on that column.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Could it be `AlA1A1` for example (note the lowercase "L")?

Comment: @Dan, your statement returned zero records. That's crazy odd because manually examining both tables reveals the Postal Code exists...

Comment: @Dukeling I checked the length of the PostalCode field in Table 1 and it's 7 characters instead of 6. It looks like there's a hidden character at the end.

Comment: @unhappymeal: As others have mentioned, make sure to check for leading/trailing blanks, newline characters, hard-to-distinguish characters such as 1 and lowercase L's, etc. Also, what RDBMS are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: What is the data type of PostalCode in the two tables?

Answer (score 2):

> When I try this query on the first table, no records are returned:
>
> ```
>   SELECT Name, PostalCode FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode = 'A1A1A1'
> ```

Well there you go. Until that works, the join won't work either. So you have some bad data. Here are a few queries you can try to help narrow down what's wrong:

```
SELECT Name, PostalCode, Len(PostalCode) FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode LIKE '%A1A1A1'

SELECT Name, PostalCode, Len(PostalCode) FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode LIKE 'A1A1A1%'

SELECT Name, PostalCode, Len(PostalCode) FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode LIKE '%A1A1A1%'

SELECT Name, PostalCode, Len(PostalCode) FROM FirstTable WHERE PostalCode LIKE 'A%1A1A1%'
```

... and more variations on that same theme.

Comment: Yep, it was bad data. There was a hidden character at the end of each postal code. Now to figure out how to trim it.

Comment: If you know the length of your postal codes, and that the bad character is at the end, you should be able to use substring() to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you may have hidden newline characters which trim will not remove.

Try running a query against the tables and check the length of the field to see if they match what your expecting.

```
SELECT Name, PostalCode, LEN(PostalCode)
FROM FirstTable
WHERE LEN(PostalCode) > 6 -- or whatever value.
```

To remove the newline characters.

```
UPDATE FirstTable SET PostalCode = SET REPLACE(REPLACE(PostalCode, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')
```

Comment: Nice! You are correct they are all 7 characters in length. So now I have to trim the new line character.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the solution using a mixture of all your suggestions. The issue was there was a hidden carriage return character at the end of the postal codes in the first table.

```
/* See if any postal codes are more than 6 characters long. */
SELECT *, LEN(PostalCode)
FROM FirstTable
WHERE LEN(PostalCode) > 6

/* Find out the ASCII code for the hidden character. */
SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(PostalCode,1))
FROM FirstTable

/* Trimming hidden new line character (ASCII Code 13) from records. */
UPDATE FirstTable
SET PostalCode = REPLACE(PostalCode,CHAR(13),'')
```

Thanks everyone!